# linking an inline swf wall post to a native ios app

Tags: ios, flash, facebook

I have a Facebook application where you can create an animation and share it on your wall. Each feed has a swf player that lets users to play the animation directly on the wall. (like any shared video). As IOS does not support flash, I have also created a native IOS application for playing those animations.

These posts can't be played on IOS devices, when touched, 'Flash Player update required' placeholder is shown.

What I want to do is, to have an alternative link for iPads to play these feeds on my native IOS app (like fb://APP_ID/video_url).

Is it possible to provide a native IOS App url for inline swf feeds?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think swf playing is possible on iOS, inline or not. The only thing you can do, is to convert that animation to an iOS compatible format, like QuickTime, or HTML5.